# Missing function Implementation in Magento2

Tags: magento2

I just observe that when I put below class declaration in constructor to avoid object manager usage, below function is showing that it not defined anywhere but with this no error coming.

```
use Magento\Backend\Model\Session as backendSession;

class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
/**
     * @var _backendSession
     */
    private $_backendSession;

public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        backendSession $backendSession
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);

       $this->_backendSession = $backendSession;
    }
public function execute()
    {
     $this->_backendSession->setFormData(false);
}
```

However failed to find definition of this function, I noticed it is 
being used in some places in core files too.

```
For eg. In vendor\magento\module-email\Controller\Adminhtml\Email\Template\Save.php around line#57

$this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')->setFormData(false);
```

Can anyone tell how it is working(if at all working) and not giving error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is assigning value in `session` by using `objectManager` that's why it is not throwing any error.(Like in core `PHP` you can assign value in session `$_SESSION["somevalue"] = "myvalue";`)

Comment: :| got It . Silly Me.